# MudBlazor TabPanel Text not updating on bound value change

Tags: data-binding, mudblazor

I have a MudDynamicTabs panel, and I want the user to be able to rename the tab after creation based on a text field in the MudTabPanel (which updates the model just fine).

I have used the code below to bind the Text to the desired object

```
<MudTabPanel ID="@tab.Id" @bind-Text="@tab.Client.Name" ShowCloseIcon="@tab.ShowCloseIcon" >
```

However, the Text only updates on another action that causes the MudDynamicTabs panel to re-render, such as an AddTab call or leaving the page.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Text` not `@bind-Text`.

Next, wherever you change the value of `tab.Client.Name`, If it is not within an blazor event like `OnClick`/`@onclick` then you have to manually call `StateHasChanged()` after you update the text, so that the component re-renders.

[Demo snippet](https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/GumxaTYgKzbyADoJ)